# why does overriding method executes twice instead of once in c#?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a  base class and a derived class . 
The base class has a simple button with a virtual protected button click method.

I am using the ovverride keyword (not using new as i want the buttonclick method in the derived class to override  the base class buttonclick method)

However , the code inside  the derived class buttonclick method  executes twice instead of once

Here is the code example

In the Base Class:

```
this.ok.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ok_Click);
    protected virtual void ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("From the Base class");
            }
```

In the  Derived Class:

```
 this.ok.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ok_Click);
 protected override void ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("From the Derived class");
            }
```

Comment: Very incomplete question. How about a nice piece of code? One possible mistake is that you subscribe the method twice to some event handler.

Comment: remove existing onclick event when overriding method then attach it again.

Comment: can provide some code examples ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't said what's actually calling the `buttonclick` method, but I suspect it's an event handler... and I suspect you're *subscribing* to it in both the subclass and base class constructors. Don't do that - you only need to subscribe once.

(If that's not the case, please show a short but complete example.)

Comment: Yes that is exactly my problem .. Thanks a lot for sorting that out Jon

Comment: You're awesome, thanks for your answer!  I'm not sure I would have ever found this on my own.